# How to show custom popup in sugarcrm onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Sugarcrm - Need to show Custom Popup on click specified field.
How to write a function to show custom popup in sugarcrm.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write your own custom Javascript or jQuery code upgrade safe manner using following step.

1. Add a reference to the javascript file you are going to add at the end of custom/modules/<>/metadata/[edit|detail]viewdefs.php

$viewdefs['Opportunities']['EditView']['templateMeta']['includes'] =
    array (
        array (
        'file' => 'path/to/file/filename.js',
        ),
    );

2. Add the javascript file you want to include into the location you referenced above.
3. Quick Repair, then browser refresh